# how to write a simple makefile for c

Tags: c, makefile

I need to write a simple make file for my.c, and so after

```
make
```

then my program can be run by

```
./my
```

my.c can be compiled by this:

```
gcc cJ/cJ.c my.c -lcrypto -o my -lm
```

Thanks
 I put this in my makefile

```
all:my
my: cJ.o my.o
 gcc cJ.o -lcrypt my.o -o my
cJ.o: cJ/cJ.c
     gcc -c cJ/cJ.c
my.o: my.c
     gcc -c my.c -lm
```

help please

Comment: We are here to help, not to do your homework for you.  Show us what you already got, and Then there are certainly people willing to help you.

Comment: i have no idea what I am doing.'my: my.o''gcc cJ/cJ.c my.c -lcrypto -o my -lm'

Comment: what you are trying to say ? could you make it more clear ? I understand you are problem in the way of your express but be clear before you post so that we can help you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, makefiles are just kind of special scripts. Every is unique, for such simple task this would be sufficient:

Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-lm -lcrypto
SOURCES=my.c cJ/cJ.c

all: my

my: $(SOURCES)
        $(CC) -o my $(SOURCES) $(CFLAGS)
```

Later you may want to use some other options such as wildcards *%.c* to compile in multiple files without having to write them in.

Alternatively:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-lm -lcrypto

MY_SOURCES = my.c cJ/cJ.c
MY_OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(MY_SOURCES))

all: my

%o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

my: $(MY_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Note that lines following each target ("my:", ...) must start with tab (\t), not spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor correction: put the `-lm` to the linking step, and there after all object files.

```
all: my
my: cJ.o my.o
    gcc cJ.o my.o -o my -lcrypt -lm
cJ.o: cJ/cJ.c
    gcc -c cJ/cJ.c
my.o: my.c
    gcc -c my.c
```

And then, you could work more with [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
all: my
my: cJ.o my.o
    gcc $^ -o $@ -lcrypt -lm
cJ.o: cJ/cJ.c
    gcc -c $^
my.o: my.c
    gcc -c $^
```

where `$@` is the target of the current rule and `$^` are the prerequisites.

See also http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html.

Comment: You could also omit the `.o:` parts entirely. Make knows how to make a `.o` from a `.c` if the basenames match. Builtin implicit rules rules!

Comment: You are right if it is ok to have `cJ.o` being created in `cJ/`.

Answer (score 0):

simple make file for your program is

```
build : 
        gcc /your_full_path_to_c_file/cJ.c my.c -lcrypto -o my -lm
```

just copy this in one file keep name of that file as makefile
then run as `make build`